# How can Windows 11 boot with Device Encryption enabled? On e.g. Ubuntu, you won't see a login screen until having logged in

Tags: windows-11, disk-encryption

I'm coming from using Ubuntu primarily for years, and now have to use Windows 11 Pro.

I have a machine with TPM 2.0, so Microsoft's website/Windows 11 tells me that now the device (disk, I hope?!) is encrypted.

However, I don't understand how I can reach the Windows login screen if the entire SSD is encrypted (as is at least what I would like to achieve)? How is it able to read the OS without a key to decrypt what's on the disk?

Or have I simply misunderstood what "Device Encryption" actually does?

Comment: How are you expecting it to ask for password to de-encrypt it, then?

Comment: Good point, but then what does device encryption actually cover of the SSD? I'd like to understand what I can trust is encrypted, because seemingly the OS can't be

Comment: BitLocker, or in the case of Windows 11 Home, Device Encryption the feature responsible for this encryption isn’t required for Windows 11. Windows 11 uses TPM for other security related purposes other than Device Encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I don't understand how I can reach the Windows login screen if the entire SSD is encrypted (as is at least what I would like to achieve)? How is it able to read the OS without a key to decrypt what's on the disk?

It *does* have a key. The BitLocker encryption key is not based on your login password – it's fully independent, very much like the LUKS passphrase on Ubuntu.

At its core, BitLocker on Windows works almost exactly like LUKS on Ubuntu. It works per-partition (not at whole-disk level), so the whole OS partition is encrypted, but there's a small part of the OS that is *not* encrypted<sup>1</sup> and is stored on a different partition, which is what prompts you for the "disk" passphrase – or uses the TPM to automatically retrieve it.

When "Device encryption" is active, the disk passphrase is encrypted ("sealed") using the TPM and stored within the disk's BitLocker metadata. When the system boots, the Windows bootloader unseals the passphrase (i.e. asks the TPM to decrypt it) and is able to unlock the encrypted C:\ volume **before** loading the OS.

By the time you reach the OS login prompt, everything has already been unlocked.

(The same can be achieved on Linux using `systemd-cryptenroll`, which uses the TPM to seal the LUKS key and stores it inside the LUKS2 header as a "token". In this case, the unencrypted Linux kernel+initrd is what prompts for passphrase or talks to the TPM.)

The full version of BitLocker (in "Pro" and higher editions of Windows) also supports using a regular passphrase without a TPM. (This doesn't count as "Device encryption" specifically, but is nevertheless the same BitLocker under the hood.) If you were to set up BitLocker that way without a TPM, you would also get a passphrase prompt from the Windows bootloader before the OS could start booting, the same way as you had on Ubuntu.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Full disk encryption" is actually done per-partition most of the time, not really full-disk. Generally the main C:\ or Linux "/" partition is encrypted but the "EFI System Partition" is not.

Both the Windows bootloader (which handles BitLocker) and the Linux kernel+initrd (which handles LUKS) would need to be stored in the unencrypted EFI System Partition. (Similarly on BIOS systems you'll have an unencrypted /boot, or a "Microsoft System Partition" which is the Windows equivalent of /boot.)

One important part of this whole setup is that the "TPM-sealed" key has *conditions for decryption* attached to it – the TPM will actually refuse to unseal it if a different OS is booted (or if Secure Boot is enabled/disabled), so that the bootloader is protected from tampering even though it's not encrypted. Plain password-based encryption typically doesn't have such protections.

Windows disks typically have a "Rescue" partition with a read-only mini-OS; this is also not encrypted (but covered by Secure Boot). If you have any custom data partitions on the same disk, those might or might not be encrypted; if they're encrypted then their passphrase is just stored somewhere within C:.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough reply.

Am I understanding correctly that the key for decrypting the passphrase for BitLocker is already one the device, and in managed/kept secure by the TPM?
I guess it's novel to me that one can have the decryption key on the device, and it's secure at the same time.

Comment: The TPM contains a "master" encryption key for everything it seals, and in theory that key cannot be physically extracted from the TPM chip. The OS can ask the TPM to encrypt some data and get the encrypted version back, and it can ask the TPM to decrypt that data again, but there's no way to decrypt the data without going through the TPM. Which means the TPM can impose conditions on when it will decrypt that data and when it won't, i.e. the OS specifies "Only decrypt this if system state is XYZ". (Most phones have a "Secure Enclave" or "TrustZone" that works the same way for data encryption.)

Comment: For example, with Windows "Device Encryption" (which implies Secure Boot), the disk encryption key is itself encrypted together with, effectively, the condition "Secure Boot must be active AND the OS must be signed using these specific keys" (i.e. official Windows keys only, not third-party OS keys). If you boot an Ubuntu liveUSB, you can certainly read the "sealed" version of the BitLocker key from the disk, but the TPM will plainly refuse to unseal it.

Comment: @BlueSwan The logic is as follows: If the PC gets stolen the thief will still need your Windows credentials to login into it. If the thief tries to circumvent the boot-process (login from different media, put disk in another computer) the disk will still be encrypted. It does also mean that if motherboard/tpm chip breaks you wil be locked out yourself and your data is lost unless you have setup BitLocker recovery or have a current backup.

Comment: @Tonny thank you very much - I think your comment was want I needed grasp user1686's very elaborate answer.

Comment: @BlueSwan I figured that :-) I'm a sysadmin in a very big corporate environment. BitLocker on all our Windows computers. (And Luks on Linux.) I get the question about the rationale for that  on average about twice a week. You're not the only one who struggles with the question why it is still protecting without the user having to enter a pin or passphrase on every boot. We always default to PIN/passphrase, but it is always possible for specific systems that need to do unattended reboots to put it on boot without asking.

Comment: @user1686 - Device Encryption does not imply Secure Boot. Device Encryption is the name of the FDE for Home bees of Windows 11. Secure Boot is a feature of UEFI. Device Encryption and BitLocker Drive Encryption are two related features but are indeed separate. Granted both are device encryption (lower case) features. Important to say that BitLocker is still optional, while Secure Boot and TPM is strictly not optional, since Windows 11 has security features that require TPM 2.0 to be enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound: As far as I can remember ([and as far as I can find out in MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-bitlocker#bitlocker-automatic-device-encryption)), it does specifically require both a TPM and UEFI Secure Boot in order to be *branded* "Device Encryption", even if BitLocker in general requires neither of those. (Most likely because Secure Boot-based TPM PCR binding is considerably less fragile – in terms of "oops, recovery key please" per month – than the PCR4 method that Windows has to use when SB is not available.)

Comment: @Ramhound: (For example, earlier in my Windows 10 Pro, I had BitLocker enabled for the system drive and it was just shown as "BitLocker" in the UI – until I enabled Secure Boot later on and the same thing started showing up as "Device Encryption", as the profile requirements were met, even though it had been set up manually and not out-of-the-box.)

Comment: @user1686 - I suppose the problem is that "Device Encryption" is a feature of devices that came with Home editions of Windows and utilized the same underline technology as BitLocker.  All the while, Device Encryption is a broad term where "Device Encryption" and BItLocker both reside within Windows. I just know I read your answer, and even though I thought understood the subject, I would have been confused if I had already not known the subject.

Answer (score 0):

From
[Device encryption in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-encryption-in-windows-ad5dcf4b-dbe0-2331-228f-7925c2a3012d) :

> Device encryption helps protect your data and it's available on a wide
> range of Windows devices.
>
> Normally when you access your data it's through Windows and has the
> usual protections associated with signing into Windows. If somebody
> wants to bypass those Windows protections, however, they could open
> the computer case and remove the physical hard drive. Then by adding
> your hard drive as a second drive on a machine they control, they may
> be able to access your data without needing your credentials.
>
> If your drive is encrypted, however, when they try to use that method
> to access the drive, they'll have to provide the decryption key (which
> they shouldn't have) in order to access anything on the drive. Without
> the decryption key the data on the drive will just look like gibberish
> to them.

Device encryption protects your disk from being stolen,
not your computer.

To protect the computer, you need to enable Bitlocker, which
requires a key to unlock the computer, if your computer qualifies
for using it. You should take good
care of the Bitlocker key and the Recovery key, or take the risk
of losing your data.

For more information see
[BitLocker overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/).